# shell script comparing two variables

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have created a script for updating some ipaddress in iptables. Hereby I'm describing the issues which I'm facing with that.

Issues:

1. Comparison not happening between two variables within a script
2. At the end of script i need to execute a command ie; service restart/stop etc and output of the commands should be visible while executing the script.

1) Here am comparing two variable strings:

```
BASE=172.31.0.0
CMD=172.31.1.0

if [[ "$CMD" == "$BASE" ]]; then
   echo "ip are same"
else
   echo "not matched"
fi
```

but there is no response/output while executing the above script. Here its not comparison is not happening..Kindly suggest a best solution to resolve this issue.

2) after executing the script I need to restart the iptables:

```
BASE=172.31.0.0
CMD=172.31.1.0

if [[ "$CMD" == "$BASE" ]]; then
   echo "ip are same"
else
   echo "not matched"
fi

service iptables restart
iptables -nvL
```

A script should display the output of the last two lines (commands). Kindly suggest me the best solution and how to do this in a best way.

Comment: Presentation award for this post. good luck

Comment: So ... exactly what shell are you using?  bash, or sh?  You know they're different, right?  Because as-is, this script works in bash and produces an error in sh.  Neither of which are what you're reporting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  Am using bash script and I am trying to execute this script by ./script.sh.

Comment: You mean that you are getting **no** output and **no** error message? That sounds weird.

Comment: @user1565390 Add `#!/bin/bash` to the first line of your script, just to assert it will be executed with `bash` when you do `./script.sh`.

Comment: I have added #!/bin/bash still am not getting any output...!! Please help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: Has the script file come from Windows? It could be the infamous \r issue. If so, use dos2unix on the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very odd. This *should work*, so if it's not working you forgot to mention something important.

How is this script being executed? Do you simply type ./script or is it executed by some service (like cron)?

Here are some of suggestions to debug:

1. Sanity check: see if bash works (perhaps your login shell isn't bash, so you didn't notice). Run this at the terminal:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c 'echo hello world'
   ```
2. It prints hello world, right? How about this:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c 'BASE=172.31.0.0; CMD=172.31.1.0; if [[ "$CMD" == "$BASE" ]]; then echo "ip are same"; else echo "not matched"; fi'
   ```

   If any of the above doesn't work, you have a problem with your bash installation.
3. Instead of executing your script with ./script.sh, run it like this:

   ```
   /bin/bash script.sh
   ```
4. Nothing? Run this:

   ```
   file script.sh
   ```

   If it ends with something like "with CRLF line terminators", then cdarke nailed it: the file was created on Windows with an improper tool. Recreate it on Linux or use dos2unix. But anyway, I doubt it because with a CRLF-ending file I get this printed:

   ```
   bash: ./script.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
   ```

   Instead of nothing at all.
5. Put those this line on the beginning of the file:

   ```
   set -x
   ```

   (below **#!/bin/bash**, if you have it). This ensures a debugging trace will be printed, showing each command as it is executed.
6. If still there is nothing shown.. put this at your script (below **set -x** if you put it):

   ```
   touch /tmp/hi-this-is-strange
   ```

   Then check if there is a **/tmp/hi-this-is-strange** file after you run the script.

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply...Can you please let me know how to remove "." within the ip-address... eg) 172.31.0.0 then by awk i need to get output as 1723100 how to do this by using "awk" tool.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think sed is more appropriate for this task: `echo 172.31.0.0 | sed 's/\.//g'`

Comment: @user1565390 Was any of of the points of my reply useful? I still don't understand what was your problem (and feel free to edit your question to add more info), but if my response solved it please accept it.